# bindableProperty can not get value?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I created a bindableproperty in a customview but it can not get value.

here is the code:

```
public string BackgroundImage
        {
            get
            {
                var image = (image)GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty);
                return image;
            }
            set => SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value);
        }
```

the image is null.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BackgroundImage), typeof(string), typeof(MyView), null);
```

the xaml code:

```
<local:MyView BackgroundImage="back.png" />
```

I do want give a string value and give it to a Image.
I have give the BackgroundImage a string value in the xaml.

Comment: You can share the code in xaml .Which will help us to solve the issue .

Comment: Also, share with us how you are assigning value to this property that would help

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have added it

Comment: What is `image` in your project ? BackgroundImage will return a string .And did you set the BindingContext in your customview?

Comment: I set BindingContext I only want to get the string value now

Comment: but why it is null?

Comment: Provide the full code of your contentpage and custom view .And I will check it on my side .

Comment: can you create a project which has the code of it? a bindingproperty a xaml file. the xaml needn't a binding value a "back.png" is fine if the bindableproperty can receive the value

Comment: It works on my side and had been verified in many other projects .So I think maybe there was an error in the code when you set up the binding .

Comment: Which X.F version are you using?, I noticed some serious bugs related to images in the latest releases, try upgrading to 4.4-pre, or use `ImageSource` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution1:**
You can get the value from the event **propertyChanged**

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
 nameof(Text),
 typeof(string),
 typeof(MyView),
 null,
 propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
 {
   var value = newValue;
   // do some thing you want .
 }
);
```

**Solution 2:**
You can set the **BindingContext**  in CustomView .

```
public MyView
{
  //...
  BindingContext = this;
  //...
}
```

Comment: will you change your answer?I will delete mine.

Comment: Sure , I will improve it with more details .